# Uniform and pointwise convergence of sequence in standard topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of functions $ f_{n} \colon [-1,0) \to \mathbb{R} $ so that $ f_{n} (x) =0$, for $ x \in [-1, - \frac{1} {n}) $ and $ f_{n} (x) =nx+1$, for $ x \in [ - \frac{1} {n}, 0)$, for each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. 
Does it converge pointwise? Does it converge uniformly?

I think it converges pointwise to $f(x) =0$ by looking at the limit of $(f_{n})$ but I am not sure about uniform convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does converge to $0$ pointwise. If the convergence is uniform then there exits $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)| <1/2$ for all $x $ for all $n >n_0$. In particular $|f_n(-\frac 1 {n^{2}}) | <1/2$. But this says $1-\frac 1 n <1/2$ for all $n >n_0$. We get a contradiction by letting $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It converges pointwise to the 0 function. To see this, note that for any $x \in [-1, 0)$, you can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x < -\frac{1}{n}$.

It does not converge uniformly. To see this, let for example $\epsilon =1$, and assume we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x) - 0|=|f_n(x)|<1$ for all $n\ge N$ and for all $x \in [-1, -0)$. Why is this wrong?

Edit: Pointed out in comments, for uniform convergence, it needs to hold for all $x \in [-1,0)$.

Comment: For $x \in [-1,-\frac 1 n)$ the in equality you have written is $0<1$, so it is not wrong.

Comment: Oups, should be $x \in [-1, 0)$. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Pointwise $f_n (x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$ in $[-1,0)$.(See other answers).

Option :

$||f||:=\sup${ $|f(x)| x \in [-1,0)$}.

$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$  in $[-1,0)$

$ \iff $

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||f_n-f||=0.$

With $f(x)=0$ we have

$||f_n||=\sup$ { $|f_n(x)|x \in [-1,0)$ } $=1$

Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}||f_n|| =1$, does not converge uniformly.